# Validating SQL in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation where I need to allow building up of SQL manually from a form. I have something like this:

```
SomeModel.where("id in (#{custom_sql})")
```

where `custom_sql` is a select statement like so:

```
SELECT u.id FROM some_model u WHERE country_iso = 'AU'
```

I want to be able to catch the StatementInvalid exception that is thrown when there is invalid SQL in the where clause, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

```
begin
  SomeModel.where("id in (#{custom_sql})")  
rescue 
  puts "Error"
end
```

But it keeps falling through without an error. Yet in `rails c`, when I do `User.where("id in (#{custom_sql})")`, it will correctly error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using joins? That seems to be a perfect solution for you code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Check the validity of your SQL statement using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. It will throw an error if your statement is invalid.

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute custom_sql
  User.where("id in (#{custom_sql})")  
rescue 
  puts "Error"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your example is unclear or misleading (probably due to your efforts to mask your actual model names)

Because if you really wanted to run the scenario you are proposing, your resulting query would be

```
select * from some_model where id in (select u.id from some_model u where country_iso = "AU"
```

(ignoring the fact that your `country_iso` field is ambiguous) You are just running

```
SomeModel.where country_iso: "AU"
```

---

So you'll need to refine your example and properly illustrate your problem, because while @zeantsoi suggests a way to help you validate your statement(s), I agree with @phoet that you are probably approaching the situation incorrectly.

Comment: Agreed that the efforts to obfuscate model names are making the code snippets difficult to understand. It would help to update with an actual example of an erroneous SQL query you'd like to catch.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, this is sql injection at it's best. you should reconsider whatever you want to accomplish.

secondly, `User.where` returns a relation. relations are lazy. lazy statements are not yet executed. so if you are doing `User.where(...).all` this should help.

Comment: Yep it's a security hole we know. It's an admin only feature, and is using a read-only user who can select from a few tables only. It's more a query tool.

Problem with .all is that this query will be called as a delayed job on a worker machine. If I call .first, will it bog my app server down?

Comment: While it's true that `User.where()` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and `User.where(...).all` returns an array, an invalid lookup in either scenario will throw an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error.

Comment: @zeantsoi no, it does not. try this in your controller: `render text: User.where('murks').to_s`

Comment: @phoet, indeed, when run on `User.where(...)`, `to_s` does indeed return a string, rather than an error. In the above scenario, would `to_s` need to be applied in order to handle the error, then?

Comment: @zeantsoi no, there is nothing special with `to_s`! the case is, that you get a proxy object, where the actual query is not yet executed. you won't get an sql-exception until you actually call an iterator method on it.